# need for one-to-many field in django

Tags: django, django-models

Imagine that you have a product which has a cover URL (cover is presented to customers on the landing page) and a list of image URLs (these images show different sides of the product)

**problem:** how to separate cover from other images?

```
class Image(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()

class Product(models.Model):
    cover = ...?
    album_images = ...?
```

Using ForeignKey in the Image model is not an option because when using `product.image_set.all()` you will get all images including the cover.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way would be:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...

class Image(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
    URL = models.URLField()
    is_cover = models.BooleanField()
```

Because of the "related_name" you can access the images from the product instance.

```
prod = Product.objects.get(pk=123)
cover = [x for x in prod.images if x.is_cover]
```

To find the cover image best to add a method to the `Product` so you can call something like `prod.get_cover()` or so.